# H2 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException when inserting a Timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, h2

A SQL query comparing timestamps works in MySQL, but fails when using an H2 database.

As an example, this is the query that produces the exception:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE time >= '2019-02-01T10:59:12.632Z' AND time <= '2019-04-12T10:59:12.632Z'`

The query is created dynamically using Java code, and the timestamps above are of type `java.time.Instant`.

I have even tried using other types of date/time objects, with the same outcome.

This query executes fine using MySQL, but throws the following error using an H2 DB:

```
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement 
 "SELECT * FROM table WHERE  time>= 2019-04-10T13[*]:31:19.498Z AND  time <= 2019-04-07T13:31:19.498Z";
 SQL statement: 
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE  time >= 2019-04-10T13:31:19.498Z AND  time<= 2019-04-07T13:31:19.498Z
```

I find it puzzling that using colon-separated timestamps cause this issue, especially since the [H2 docs use similar timestamps](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html?highlight=delimiter&search=delimiter#timestamp)

Comment: Rather than building the query string dynamically you should use a prepared statement and pass the instants as query parameters.

Comment: @OleV.V. This is the correct solution. I am using Spring Boot, and so I just passed the two Instants as parameters to the `jdbcTemplate.query()` method.
Thank you.

Comment: @OleV.V. I have done so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Spring Boot's `JdbcTemplate` and creating my queries as follows:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE  time >= " + startTime + " AND " +  " time <= " + endTime, (rs, i) -> Accessor.readFromResultSet(rs));
```

with the date Strings passed in as `Instant` objects.

The solution, thanks to @OleV.V's comment, was to pass the date objects in as an Object argument:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE  time >= ? AND time <= ?", new Object[]{startTime, endTime}, (rs, i) -> Accessor.readFromResultSet(rs));
```

Answer (score 1):

try converting date string properly

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time >= str_to_date('2019-02-01 10:59:12.632 ', '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f') 
      AND time <=  str_to_date( '2019-04-12 10:59:12.632 ' , '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f')
```